# CSGO Operation Breakout last mission?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

SO I've been deleting a couple of missions (competitive) with maps that aren't popular (esp Breakout Maps). I do try to find a game but I just can't, so I delete 'em. Most of the maps I get for competitive are Operation breakout and those unpopular ones like Cache. Maybe it's just my location and ping but I just can't find a game. 
Anyway, after that I'm stuck with this mission: Competitive: Cache. I can't delete it. It's been like 2 weeks or so. I do the second other mission (Casual, Deathmatch, etc). I'm almost done with my 13th mission, what's gonna happen when I'm done with my 14th? Am I gonna get a new mission drop or do I have to play the Competitive Cache to get the golden coin?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The majority of the hostage scenario maps can take a good 3-5 minutes queuing to get a game. Have you waited this long?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and thought I was going to have to do Comp Wins to get the Match Coin.

The thing is, mission drops have a limit per week, similar to item drops.

So just wait the next week, go to regular servers, and get mission drops.  That's what I did, even though I had a Comp Wins in Mist mission (still have to finish it).

YOu still have until Oct. 2nd to finish all your missions, which still is a good 4 weeks, so roughly 20 mission drops to get that gold coin.